# When two different methods call on regular interval to the same controller, after some time it will automatically redirect to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress-mvc

I am using a devexpress control with asp.net mvc 5.
I have a view in that i have two different grid.I have two partial view methods in single controller for each grid.
I am refreshing each grid at some interval time to fetch data and bind it to gridview.
i put an authorize filter on controller level.
On the starting both gridview are refreshing but after some time it will automatically redirect to login page.
Please do needful.

Comment: How long will the authentication cookie be valid?

Comment: I set 20minutes authentication time for session.

Comment: You should make that 20 minutes sliding. Everytime the page is refreshed that authentication cookie should get a new expiration date/time